# How to properly setup cURL in Android

Tags: android, curl, android-ndk

I've been trying to setup [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) in Android. However I get confused setting it up. I am using windows7 64bit, the latest ADT and NDK, and tried to follow [this](http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.com/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html) but I don't have Linux, nor a am I able to setup a repository. Searching around, I have not found a step-by-step setup. Either they don't explain well how to setup or they are outdated (4 - 5 years ago) which means most of the steps are obsolete. I'm just beginner with cURL so I don't exactly have ample knowledge with setting it up to use it. Thanks in advance.